# Odd graphics error -- "division by 0"

Tags: graphics, errors

When I compile this code in `xelatex`...

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{texMemo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\memoto{You}
\memofrom{Me}
\memodate{\today}
\memosubject{Some stuff}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{/Dropbox/foo/bar/baz/my_cool_logo_file.png}}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

I get errors about `unable to load picture or PDF file` and `package graphics Error: division by 0`. I did find [this page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-divzero), which looked promising, but it didn't solve the problem. I also had a look at the `grffile` package, but it didn't seem to offer anything I could use. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you point to a location where `texMemo.cls` is available?

Comment: The package can be obtained from http://www.oak-tree.us/2010/08/02/texmemo. I tried your code, apart from the grapics file not being available at all, there is no problem. I assume, that either your path to the file is wrong or the image file is corrupted. But it seems to be a nice class

Comment: I've checked it a couple of times. I'm pretty sure the image file is intact, because I can open it in Preview and import it into a Word document. I'm pretty sure the path is correct, because the same problem comes up when I try to use a different image file, with a different suffix (`.jpg` as opposed to `.png`), in a different directory. Could it be a permissions problem? I wouldn't have thought so, because I use `\includegraphics` all the time with no issues, but maybe this is a special case?

Comment: Can you add `[demo]` option ? I mean `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. If it complains about option clash remove that option and put `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` before document class command.

Comment: I still think it's the path.  Usually Dropbox doesn't mount at the top level.  Are you sure it's not `~/Dropbox` or `/Users/crmdgn/Dropbox`?

Comment: Very easy way to test: copy the image file to the working directory, delete the leading parts of the path from the filename in the source, and try compiling.

Comment: @percusse: I have checked the `demo` option, there were no complains. Probably Matthew's proposition is the solution.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang OK, you're right. It was the path. If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it and award the bounty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `unable to load picture or PDF file` error is a clue that something's wrong, not on the TeX side but on the filesystem side.  Possible causes include a corrupted image file, a permissions-protected image file, or a nonexistent image file.  The `division by 0` error is secondary to the first: TeX is trying to draw a box without having dimensions to form its corners.

If you can open and view the image with a previewer then it's likely the problem is not with the file itself (or its permissions, since TeX is running as you).  So I guessed the nonexistent file, i.e., bad file name.  Knowing that Dropbox usually doesn't mount at the top level of the file system was another clue that the path was wrong.

cfr's check that this is the problem is worth repeating.

> copy the image file to the working directory, delete the leading parts of the path from the filename in the source, and try compiling.

It's another example of how simplifying the non-compiling document down to the barest bones can isolate the error.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the excellent inputs by others, another possible issue could be with the filename.
The system photo viewer does not differentiate between Upper and Lower case extensions. That is to say, An image named as `IMG.JPG` as well as `IMG.jpg` can be opened by system Photo/Image viewer. However, in your .tex file, you should be careful.
`\includegraphics{IMG.JPG}` is different from `\includegraphics{IMG.jpg}`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was simply a `tabular` in a `resizebox`,  with a missing `\end{tabular}%`.

Adding the missing `\end{tabular}` at the end of the `resizebox` fixed it.

So, in case this helps anyone, first check that you do not have any missing `\end{...}` statement somewhere.

Comment: Yes, a curious and possibly deceiving error message.